# Joomla 3 Calendar function positioning & icon

Tags: css, joomla, calendar, joomla3.0

I'm working with a custom Joomla 3 component that has some date selection fields in a form. The calendar popup displays, but much higher on the page and it is missed. I need to modify the styling, but do not know where.

In Firebug, I see it is embedded styling of absolute positioning and data given for top and left positioning. I can't find where this is coming from.

Also, I just have a small box showing to click on and get the calendar. Need assistance also to get an icon in place there. Code I'm using currently is:

```
echo JHTML::calendar($date, 'startDate', 'startDate', '%m/%d/%Y');
```

Note that the field DOES work... just not well due to the popup being so far away. Thanks for any tips and direction here!

Comment: Works fine for me on Joomla 3.3. The calendar popup appears directly above the calendar field as expected. Could you provide a link to your site so we can get a live preview? It's rather hard to tell without seeing anything as it could be various reasons

Comment: sorry, can't. It's local access only at this point. Plus it's on Joomla 3.2.4... stuck there due to running PHP 5.3.3. Must be something in this component that I can't find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. It was template related. The CSS file had "position: relative" assigned to "body". I removed this, then the popup calendar used the absolute positioning that it wanted to.

For the icon, I borrowed the CSS from the core Joomla Prostar template for buttons, icons, etc. All good!